# Delphi: unselect selected items in Tree View

Tags: delphi, select, treeview

There is a Tree View, `MultiSelect:=true`.

If to select all items then it is impossible to unselect or to select again but others. I think I need to do `TreeView1.Selected.Selected:=false;` on `TForm1.TreeView1Click`. But how to know if a click was not on controls: items, buttons?

A video: http://liga-installer.realservers.info/select.mp4

Is a code below normal?

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Item: TTreeNode;
 begin

  Item :=TTreeView(Sender).GetNodeAt(TTreeView(Sender).ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos).X,
  TTreeView(Sender).ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos).y);

  if (not Assigned(Item)) and (TTreeView(Sender).SelectionCount>0) then TTreeView(Sender).Select(nil, []);
 end;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can show a video. I create a new project, select all items and then cannot unselect.

Comment: Please see: http://liga-installer.realservers.info/select.mp4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to hold down the Shift key while clicking the first selected item. You can also deselect one item at a time by Ctrl-clicking it.

But I agree it is counter-intuitive. I'd do

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if not Assigned(TreeView1.GetNodeAt(X, Y)) then
    for i := 0 to TreeView1.Items.Count - 1 do
      TreeView1.Items[i].Selected := false;
end;
```

Comment: How to unselect all at once by clicking? It is inconvenient to hold a key again and click.

Comment: "I think I need to do TreeView1.Selected.Selected:=false; on TForm1.TreeView1Click. But how to know if a click was not on controls: items, buttons?"

Comment: @maxfax: Use the `GetNodeAt` or the `GetHitTestInfoAt` function.

Comment: To deselect all `TreeView1.Select(nil, []);`

Comment: I looked at the video and tried this in XE, and I get the same behaviour. I think it is a bug and should be reported in QC, if it wasn't already.

Comment: This behaviour appears to be by design and has been present since I first used Delphi tree view. It is a very counter intuitive design. In my apps I hack the VCL to make the control behave better.

Comment: Also, is mouse down the right place for this? Shouldn't it be mouse up?