# Deselect a treeview's element in delphi

Tags: delphi, treeview

I just need to deselect an item of a treeview in delphi.

Here my failed try:

1) `TreeView1.Selected.Selected := False;`

2) `TreeView1.Selected.Data := nil;`

3) `TreeView1.Select(nil,[]);`

4)

```
  for i := 0 to TreeView1.Items.Count - 1 do  
      TreeView1.Items[i].Selected := false;
```

5)

```
  TreeView1.MultiSelect := true;
  for i := 0 to TreeView1.Items.Count - 1 do
      TreeView1.Items[i].Selected := false;
      TreeView1.MultiSelect := false;
```

6)

```
var
nulla : TTreeNode;
```

---

```
nulla := nil;
TreeView1.Select(nulla, []);
```

7) `TreeView1.ClearSelection(False);`

8) `TreeView1.ClearSelection(True);`

They ALL crash my program (except for 8, it simply doesn't do anything), how can i do this?
My goal is to simply deselect clicking on a white space.

Comment: Similar question, [`Delphi: unselect selected items in Tree View`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6837813/576719). But you seem to have tried all proposed solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `TTreeView.Selected` property to `nil`, or setting the `TTreeNode.Selected` property to `False`, is the correct approach.

1 and 2 will crash if `TTreeView.Selected` is already `nil`, but the other approaches should work fine, provided that the `TTreeView` pointer is a valid pointer to begin with.